# Force Stash to output https

Tags: stash, ssl

I've inherited an old EE site.  I'm trying to get everything running on https.  I can get EE to serve up most images via https but it seems like when stash is used, it doesn't use https.  Is there a way to force it?

```
{exp:stash:get_list:nested name="home_slider"}
    <a href="{link}"><img src="{image}" alt="{if '{alt_text}'}{alt_text}{if:else}{headline}{/if}"></a>
{/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I needed to clear the ce cache directory and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Stash will simply return whatever value was stored in the token `{link}`, so the solution is to find where that token is created and adjust the code there.

If you are not sure how to do this, post the code segment concerned and someone will suggest how to correct.

HTH

> PS - To get better answers it helps if you can add information about
> what version of EE you are using (and sometimes what version of
> php)... thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  It's EE 2.72
Here's the template code: https://pastebin.com/reFJh5my